# Android share file: can I know when the file has been shared or the chooser was cancelled?

Tags: android, share

I have an application with a `Share` option. When the user clicks on it, a `file` to be shared is created and then a `chooser` is shown to ask the user how does he want to share it (mail, skype, google drive...). Once the file has been shared or the chooser is cancelled I want to delete the file since it's no longer needed.

I want the filename to have the current date, so overriding the same file each time is not an option. Is there any way to know when this file isn't needed anymore??

To share the file I use this code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/csv");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, csv);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about this, but have you tried replacing `startActivity` with `startActivityForResult` and checking if the `resultCode == RESULT_OK` or `resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED` in the `onActivityResult()`? If the result is `OK`, you can delete the file. Don't delete if the result is `CANCELLED`. I am speculating of course.

Comment: I was about to say: "Yeah, I tried it and onResult isn't called". Then I saw I had a filter in my LogCat and that's why my log messages weren't seen -.- Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `startActivity`, the chooser needs to be started using `startActivityForResult`. The chooser isn't closed until it's cancelled or the file is shared, so the file can be deleted in `onActivityResult`.